# Django: Change the value of a related model instance attribute, so that updated value is returned when the related instance is accessed later

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I'm having problem to understand how I can change values of related model instance attributes, so that the updated values are returned when I read the model instance attributes elsewhere.

In the example below, I'd like this to output 1 when index() is run. However, despite incrementing temp_attribute in init(), the printed value is always 0 (initial value), not 1 (updated value). Is it possible to achieve without saving the information to the database? I'd like to avoid that since I don't need these values to persist from one session to another.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    def init(self):
        for comment_instance in self.comment_set.all():
            comment_instance.init()

class Comment(models.Model):
    blogpost = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost)
    temp_attribute = 0

    def init(self):
        self.temp_attribute += 1
```

**views.py**

```
from models import BlogPost, Comment

def index(request):
    blogpost = BlogPost.objects.create()
    comment = Comment.objects.create(blogpost=blogpost)
    blogpost.init()
    for comment_instance in blogpost.comment_set.all():
        print comment_instance.temp_attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to achieve without saving the information to the database?

No. Any changes made to local models are temporary until saved, since accesses from elsewhere will retrieve the model fresh from the database. If you need a value to persist through the session then you should [associate it with the session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) instead.